# Validation for required gets triggered on page render in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a textarea in my form which is bound to a property `remark`.

When I am adding the `[Required]` annotation, it is getting triggered before submit button.

I have 2 from on the .cshtml

First form also has submit button. On click when they get submitted, I fetch some data from controller on post and then render second form.

But `Required` validator gets triggered to `Remark` textarea.

```
<label class="required">@Html.DisplayName("Remark")</label>
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Remark, new { @class = "", @min = "1" ,maxlength = "255", placeholder = "Remark" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Remark)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it was a post call and property is having required validation. this triggers. I have clreaed the sate in my post call...